# Codeigniter all routes not working except defauly

Tags: codeigniter-3

I am tring to edit a project with minor changes. i downloaded the code from hosting to localhost.
the only code change i made is
from

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/autosure';
```

anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. Rewrite Engine is not working at all. edited apache.conf Changed

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```

Answer (score 0):

add `index.php` to URL

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/autosure/index.php';
```

Or add `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: my styles and images disappeared when i do like that. and also it showing the 'index.php' in the address bar. i dont want to have that also.

Comment: add add htacces so

Comment: //my styles and images disappeared when i do like that. and also it showing the 'index.php' in the address bar. i dont want to have that also//

i added the htaccess aswell

Comment: can you help me i am really stuck

Comment: Found the issue. Rewrite Engine is not working at all. edited apache.conf
Changed 
`AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`